# Is there anything I should be careful with when reinstalling Ubuntu on a multiboot system?

Tags: upgrade, dual-boot

I have a Win 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 multiboot system on my laptop. I am planning to upgrade Ubuntu, but I'd like to do it with a CD and make a new installation.

I am wondering if there is anything I need to know about before I start altering my system. 
I think I just have to format and choose the partition where my current Ubuntu OS is and set the boot for the entire HD and that way thing will go smoothly and after the installation the screen will appear again (the screen where I can choose between Win7 and Ubuntu). Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to upgrade your Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.10, then you can use a liveDVD or a liveUSB to upgrade it.

If you want a fresh install, then you could choose the "something else" option and format your Ubuntu partition and continue installing 12.10 there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info To Do. If I choose the "something else" option, it wont mess with the boot part of the laptop. Right?

Comment: The Ubuntu installer will update the bootloader (Grub) of the drive where it is installed. Since you'll not be changing the partition table of your drive, there shouldn't be adverse effects on your system. To be on the safe side, it's always a good idea to back up your data before starting. One can always do a mistake and mess up things.

Comment: GRUB2 will be installed with the new version of Ubuntu, and the boot menu will then offer a choice between the new version of Ubuntu and your previously installed Windows 7.  Effectively, the new version of Ubuntu overwrites the old version.  The boot menu simply offers the new version of Ubuntu instead of the original version.